# Searching data from txt file in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, search

I have a `.txt` file in which some data is present, when I stored it in an array I got 50000 words. I want to search the data from text file according to user input and show it on `UITableview` cell, how is it possible ? 
Can any body help me?

Here is my code to read data from `.txt` file in `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myList" ofType:@"txt"];
NSError *error;
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filepath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if (error)
NSLog(@"Error reading file: %@", error.localizedDescription);

// maybe for debugging...
NSLog(@"contents: %@", fileContents);

NSArray *listArray = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSLog(@"items = %d", [listArray count]);
```

Comment: Rather than a major problem, it is a Minor i.e. a Logical issue. Your logics are not clear.
    My suggestion : Run a function with a `for-loop` for `[listArray count]` each time user hit a key in `UItextField` and match the 'UITextfield.text' to the current element in the loop. If the match is found store it in the array with `addObject` and show the array data in the `UItableView` with` [table reload]` code.

Comment: according to your way i know that it,s easy and i have do it but it is valid way to store data with 50000 item at first then how many memory it will use and it is not a way like if i have an array of 200000 items so??

Comment: This is part 2 of a question. I hope somebody will help you on this. My `memory` concepts are weak.

Comment: instead of writing to .txt file use coredata. So that you can use nspredicate and/or nsfetchrequestcontroller

Comment: @Johnykutty can we not work without any database , i dont want to store it in database or array, i just want to fetch the data from txt according to user input , is it possible or not?

Comment: if you write to file and read it then you should read the entire file thin filter it. it may cause memory shoot up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use fast enumeration using block. Those are fastest of all for loop iteration. But changing the value in that array at time of enumeration could cause a crash.

[Here is a link](http://nshipster.com/enumerators/) of how to use block enumeration

[Here is a link](http://darkdust.net/writings/objective-c/nsarray-enumeration-performance) of how it performance wise.

Hope this helps you!!